# How to pass two params to a function in drools' decision table?

Tags: drools

As the title says, I use an excel table as decision table of drools, the result entity has too many attributes, so I want to use a map to hold all the attributes, here comes the question: how should I pass two params, one as a key, and the other as the value? Any reply will be thankfull!

Comment: As usual, in Java and in dozens of other programming languages. Do you really need an example?

Comment: Yes, an example will be helpful, I'm new to drools.

Comment: Sorry for not describing clearly. I mean, I want to pass two params to a function in decision table, how to definite the function's params, and, which form the two params should be passed.

Comment: The Drools Manual describes how to define a function. It's almost the same syntax as a (static) Java method. I'm not going to copy the manual as an answer.

Comment: I got answer at https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch06.html. Thanks.